# jQuery animate a value of one elem of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problems to animate a value of a certain element when selecting it with the class, instead it will animate all elements of that class.

```
$('.class').parent().hover( 
                function() {
                   $({ value: $(this).val() }).animate( .... );
                   ...
                }, function() {
                   $({ value: $(this).val() }).animate( .... );
                   ...
                });
```

Unfortunately due to a plugin i use for creating a slider i have to use the .parent() selector, so i can not use ..

```
$('.parent') -> $('.class', this)
```

.. what i think it would solve it.

I have three elements with the ".class"-class and they are all three animated whenever i hover one of them.

*further explanation:*
The html is only one thing:

```
<input type="text" value="0" class="class" />
```

The Plugin creates a canvas above the input and the input is used as the value for the animated bar. It also creates a div wrapping around this two elements. Like so :

```
<div>
  <canvas>
  <input ... >
</div>
```

I'm sure i can find a easy solution by using id's and writing it multiple times in the code with the id's as selector, but i hope for a more elegant way to solve this.

**[Here the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWsuP/6/)**

Comment: You'll need to find a way to identify the element you want. How do the `.class` element's hierarchies differ?

Comment: **.parent([selector])** try $('.class').parent('.parent')

Comment: `class=".class"` typo?

Comment: I think they don't differ from each other, i have added some more info about the hierarchies. I hoped there is a way to select the element that is actually hovered.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your example to give us a better idea of what your issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you know that the `<canvas>` tag will always be created, why not just use the `<canvas>` tag as the selector to provide context?

```
$('canvas').hover( 
    function() {
        var that = $(this);
        $({ value: $(this).next() }).animate(
            ...
            progress: function() {
                that.next().val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
            }
        );
    }, function() {
        var that = $(this);
        $({ value: $(this).next().val() }).animate(
            ...
            progress: function() {
                that.next().val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
            }
        );
    });
```

[NEW Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWsuP/9/)

Comment: Yea that seams to work, but there is one thing. When you mouseover another canvas before the first one is cleared, it will just stop at the current value. Seems like the hover function thinks its still at the same canvas, but it increases another next()'s elements value. Is there a way to carry that exact element that you activated at the first hover function over to the second hover function?

Comment: Whoops, whoops made a scoping error. I've updated the code to fix that. Thanks for pointing that out. `$(this)` was being stored out of context :)

Comment: may i ask what the `var that = $(this);` is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try wrapping it in an event listener instead:

```
$(function(){
    $('.class').on('hover',function(){
        $({value:$(this).parent().val()}).animate( ...)
    })
});
```

Comment: I have to use the `.parent()` for the hover since the `.class` element is only used for the value. However, if i do so wouldn't it be the same thing as my original code?